# Struts2- extending action classes and thread safety

Tags: struts2

I understand the instance variables on an action class are thread-safe since action classes are instantiated per request. But I have this need for extending action classes and I'm concerned about the thread-safety.

Say, for example I have some common attributes and a few methods handling those attributes among several action classes. I prefer to put them in a single action class and make that extend the `ActionSupport`. And all action classes will then extend the base action class that I just created. My question is, are the instance variables on the base action class thread-safe? Does S2 manage the base action class at all?

Also what makes an action class an action class to be managed by the S2 and instantiated per request? Getting declared in the `struts.xml`? Extending `ActionSupport` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused about how Java works.
If you have a class `A` and a class `B extends A`, when you instantiate `B` there is a `B`. It's not like there's a single instance of `A` backing all instances of `B`. There's no "management of base classes".

Classes declared as actions either via XML, annotations, or convention are instantiated by the Struts action instantiation mechanism. Extending `ActionSupport` has (almost) nothing to do with it, the only time it *might* have something to do with it is because `ActionSupport` implements the `Action` interface.

Comment: Well, in this case, I want the base action class (which will not be declared in the struts xml) as well to be instantiated once per request which is why I was asking if it's managed by S2.

Comment: Why the downvote ? I guess that hater is still out there... +1

Comment: @mystarrocks No sweat, I know who it was.

Comment: @DaveNewton, can you tell me who is ? He's randomly downvoting some of my answers too from today :)

Answer (score 2):

> Also what makes an action class an action class to be managed by the S2 and instantiated per request? **Getting declared in the struts.xml**? Extending ActionSupport class?

*Getting declared in the `struts.xml`*: yes, is that that turns a Java class into an Action.

And every Action class is thread-safe because it's ThreadLocal, no matter what it extends nor implements. Every request of every user will have its own copy of each Action class.

P.S: The other classes (not declared in `struts.xml`) are not *"(action classes) not managed by S2 and instantiated per request"*, they're simply NOT Actions.

Comment: Are there thread-safety issues if the base class contains static objects? Just curious... btw, i gave you an upvote!

Comment: @Sumit Static variables can always cause threading issues if access to them isn't synchronized and you rely on absolute integrity. If you're only *reading*, it's not a problem.